# Iterating an array of autoclosures in Swift causes compilation error

Tags: swift

I submitted a bug report on this to Apple, but wanted to be sure I wasn't doing something stupid. Consider the following code:

```
func coalesce(values: @autoclosure () -> Any?...) -> Any? {
    for value in values {
        if let found = value() {
            return found
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

This lazily returns the first non-optional value. Except that it does not compile. The compiler errors are:

1. Value of optional type `protocol<>?` not unwrapped. Did you mean to use '!' or '?'?
2. Invalid use of '()' to call a value of non-functional type `'protocol<>?'`

When I first saw this I thought my syntax was bad. But the plot thickens. If you iterate the array the old-fashioned way, everything works!

```
func coalesce(values: @autoclosure () -> Any?...) -> Any? {
    for v in 0..<values.count {
        if let found = values[v]() {
            return found
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Anyone have any insight on this? Is my syntax incorrect? Is there some other way to call an autoclosure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems, the problem is around iterating autoclosured values. Maybe the compiler could not assume the correct type of the elements.

I found a workaround here:

```
func coalesce(values:@autoclosure () -> Any? ... ) -> Any? {
    for value: () -> Any? in values {
        if let found = value() {
            return found
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

BTW, I'm really surprised we can do like this:

```
let foo: @autoclosure () -> Int = 42
foo()
```

So, this also works:

```
func coalesce(values:@autoclosure () -> Any? ... ) -> Any? {
    for value: @autoclosure () -> Any? in values {
    //         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
        if let found = value() {
            return found
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: I've marked this correct, but I still regard it as a bug. I see no reason why the compiler cannot correctly infer the value.

Comment: Where by "correctly infer the value" I meant "correctly infer the type."